# Kafka: enabling multiple authentication methods

Tags: authentication, oauth, apache-kafka

I have worked on setting the authentication for Kafka clients in past. I have I have refered:

1. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security
2. https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html#sasl-configuration-for-kafka-brokers

And other links as well.

As mentioned in docs we need to have jaas configuration file to specify the authentication method, I had one like below:

```
KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required
    LoginStringClaim_sub="admin";
};
```

Which basically adds the OAuth authentication for kafka clients.

The question is - **can I have multiple authentication methods enabled on kafka broker**

I mean can I enable both OAuthBearer and PLAIN authentication on Kafka, and let the **client** authenticate by any one of these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found how we can do it.

Multiple SASL mechanisms can be enabled on the broker simultaneously while each client has to choose one mechanism.

In JAAS config file, we have to specify the configuration for the multiple login modules as below:

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required
  LoginStringClaim_sub="admin";

  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  user_admin="admin-secret"
  user_alice="alice-secret";
};
```

Then we have to enable the SASL mechanisms in server.properties:

```
# List of enabled mechanisms, can be more than one
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=OAUTHBEARER,PLAIN
```

And Then Specify the SASL security protocol and mechanism for inter-broker communication in server.properties

```
# Configure SASL_SSL if SSL encryption is enabled, otherwise configure SASL_PLAINTEXT
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL

# Configure the appropriate inter-broker protocol
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
```

Credit to - https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html#enabling-multiple-sasl-mechanisms

Answer (score 0):

You need the configs below(If the Oauth2 is using AAD):

```
listeners=SASL://0.0.0.0:9770
advertised.listeners=SASL://localhost:9770
listener.security.protocol.map=SASL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
    
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN 
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=OAUTHBEARER,PLAIN

listener.name.sasl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="AdminName" password="AdminPassword" user_UserName="UserPassword";
listener.name.sasl.plain.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=com.XXXAuthenticateCallbackHandler

listener.name.sasl.oauthbearer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required clientId='BrokerApplicationId' clientSecret='BrokerApplicationSecret' scope='BrokerApplicationId/.default';
listener.name.sasl.oauthbearer.sasl.login.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
listener.name.sasl.oauthbearer.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerValidatorCallbackHandler

sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/BrokerTenantId/discovery/v2.0/keys
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/BrokerTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

super.users=User:AdminName
```

If you need authorization too, you need to add more configs below:

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
```

Plain user config:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="UserName" password="UserPassword";
```

Oauth user config:

```
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/ClientTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
sasl.login.callback.handler.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler
sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.jaas.config= \
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required \
    clientId='ClientApplicationId' \
    scope='BrokerApplicationId/.default' \
    clientSecret='ClientApplicationSecret';
```